# Question from Knuth problem on primitive networks and Young Tableaux of a particular shape.

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux

It seems like from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4497.pdf) that chains in the brahut in $S_n$ order are length $\binom{n}{2}$ and there is a bijection with young tableaux of shape $\lambda = (n-1, n-2, \ldots,1)$.

[Knuth](https://books.google.com/books?id=e3wLBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=primitive+network+sorting&source=bl&ots=10YsK4NrzN&sig=dda1jUvIDJ8azyet8VYCeynkQxI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8uPyy76TcAhVprVQKHXrKDc4Q6AEIQDAC#v=onepage&q=primitive%20network%20sorting&f=false) in problem 38 seems to say there is a bijection between young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and primitive sorting networks (where all of the comparators are ordered in a list).

It seems like the partial product of the comparitors (when applied to $t$ the order reversing permutation as transpositions), produces a chain in the brahut ordering.

${\rm inv}(t) \supset {\rm inv}(\tau_1 t) \supset{\rm inv}(\tau_2 \tau_1 t) \supset ... \supset {\rm inv}(e) = \emptyset$

Where

- $t \in S_n$ sends $t(k) = n-k+1$.
- $e$ is the identity element of $S_n$,
- $\tau_i$ is the transposition associated the $i$th comparator.
- ${\rm inv}(\sigma) = \{(i, j) : 1 \leq i < j \leq n {\rm and } \sigma(i) > \sigma(j)\}$ for $\sigma \in S_n$

Is there a tidy way to state this bijection with young tableaux of shape $\lambda$?

Comment: The first paragraph is rather opaque. Are you talking about the [Bruhat order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_order), and if so then weak or strong, and on which set of generators of $S_n$? Also, since the word Bruhat doesn't appear anywhere in that 65-page document, could you be more specific about where to look for the correspondence?